# How to insert character after 3rd and 5th number with AWK

Tags: regex, bash, replace, awk, substring

I have

```
Andrew 123123
Mick 234234
Steve 345345
Bob 456456
```

need to out

```
Andrew 123-1-23
Mick 234-2-34
Steve 345-3-45
Bob 456-4-56
```

Try to use some regex replace but dont khow how to remember fisrt "substr" to replace it to "substr-".

Comment: Does it have to be awk? I'd use `sed 's/\(.\)\(..\)$/-\1-\2/'`

Comment: Ya, I need to use exactly awk =(

Comment: Your system does not have `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly tools better suited to the job but, if you *must* use `awk`, you can do it with:

```
{print $1" "substr($2,1,3)"-"substr($2,4,1)"-"substr($2,5)}
```

as per the following transcript:

```
$ echo 'Andrew 123123
Mick 234234
Steve 345345
Bob 456456' | awk '{print $1" "substr($2,1,3)"-"substr($2,4,1)"-"substr($2,5)}'

Andrew 123-1-23
Mick 234-2-34
Steve 345-3-45
Bob 456-4-56

$ echo 'Andrew 123456
Mick abcdef
Steve 314159
Bob xxxyzz' | awk '{print $1" "substr($2,1,3)"-"substr($2,4,1)"-"substr($2,5)}'

Andrew 123-4-56
Mick abc-d-ef
Steve 314-1-59
Bob xxx-y-zz
```

Comment: Thats Perfect! One more question, how to apply with replacement to only 7 length numbers?

Comment: @Orion, that probably should have been in your original question, or another question, but that's when you'd use filters, along the lines of: `awk 'length($2)==7{print ...}'`. Keep in mind your sample data has a length of _six._

Comment: In this case only changed lines will be printed

Comment: finally it's `awk 'length($2)!=7{print} length($2)==7{print $1" "substr($2,1,3)"-"substr($2,4,2)"-"substr($2,6)}' awk`

Comment: @Orion `awk 'length($2)==7{$2=substr($2,1,3)"-"substr($2,4,1)"-"substr($2,5)}1'`

Answer (score 0):

if you can use perl (ok, ok it is equal to sed, and \cite{@Beta} already told us how to do it :)...

```
perl -pe 's/\b(\d{3})(\d)(\d{3})\b/$1-$2-$3/g'
```

You need to adapt the numbers to your length...

**Testing:**

using a previous example \cite{@paxdiablo}

```
$ echo 'Andrew 123456
Mick abcdef
BBB 12345
Steve 314159
Bob xxxyzz' | perl -pe 's/\b(\d{3})(\d)(\d{2})\b/$1-$2-$3/g'

Andrew 123-4-56
Mick abcdef
BBB 12345
Steve 314-1-59
Bob xxxyzz
```

Answer (score 0):

This really is a job for sed since it's just a simple substitution on single lines, but here's GNU awk on a modified input file that contains a couple of 7-digit 2nd fields plus one 6 and one 8:

```
$ cat file
Andrew 1231239
Mick 234234
Steve 3453457
Bob 45645623
$
$ awk '{$2=gensub(/^(...)(.)(...)$/,"\\1-\\2-\\3","",$2)}1' file
Andrew 123-1-239
Mick 234234
Steve 345-3-457
Bob 45645623
```